# Hide UIBarButtonItem but not make is nil

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem

Is it possible to hide UIBarButtonItem (rightButton of navigationBar) but not making it nil? In my application I have a condition

```
if(self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem == nil)
```

which is really important. But hiding the barButton is equally important.

Comment: how about checking whether it is hidden rather than nil ?

Comment: There is no Hidden property of *UIBarButtonItem:* so you have to nil it

Comment: but why dont you want to make it nil ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is use the `initWithCustomView` property of `UIBarButtonItem`. Set up a `UIButton` and use `initWithCustomView` and assign it to this button. `UIButton` has hiding and unhiding property.

```
UIButton*someButton=[UIButton UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
UIBarButtonItem*someBarButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:someButton];

//To Hide/Unhide
[someButton setHidden:YES/NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide your button by which you have made your barbutton ....

```
UIButton *button1=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button1 setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 2.0, 45.0, 40.0)];
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(showLeft:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"anyImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:button1];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button;

[button1 setHidden:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44355059/8089019) to similar question. It's applicable here too.

It adds `isHidden` property to UIBarButtonItem.