# Show or hide UIBarButtonItem in UIToolbar programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

```
var toolBar: UIToolbar!
let nextBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Next", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "nextButtonPressed")
self.toolBar.setItems([nextBarButton], animated: true)
```

How to hide nextButton in ToolBar?
I used the following code and it did not work.

```
self.toolbar.items.indexOf(1).hidden = true
```

Comment: and nextBarButton.hidden = true ?

Comment: Check below link. I gives solution to your problem
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18115434/1850983

Answer (score 3):

This answer is inspired by [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43891129/8089019)

I will improve on it and make all the work programmatically. No need to update/set the class of the `UIBarButtonItem` instance to use the new subclass anymore.

We could just add `isHidden` attribute to the `UIBarButtonItem`. Then just use it as you want.

```
extension UIBarButtonItem {
   var isHidden: Bool = false {
      didSet {
          isEnabled = !isHidden
          tintColor = isHidden ? UIColor.clear : UIColor.black
      }
   }
}
```

In your case, after you add the extension (outside any class). You could use it as:

```
self.toolbar.items.indexOf(1).isHidden = true
```

Comment: How do you get past this error: "Extensions must not contain stored properties"

Answer (score 1):

UIBarButton does not have a "hidden" property so you cannot hide. You can remove it.  Since you only have one button on the toolbar, you can clear all the items on the toolbar.

```
toolBar.setItems([], animated: true)
```

If you wanted to remove a specific item, you can use the index.

```
    var items = toolBar.items
    items?.removeAtIndex(0)
    toolBar.setItems(items, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a 'next' button, the standard way to handle when there is nothing to move to next is to simply disable it like this:

```
nextBarButton.enabled = NO;
```

The icon is greyed out automatically too.

Answer (score 0):

You can add simple function, for hiding state

```
extension UIBarButtonItem {
    func set(hide: Bool) {
        isEnabled = !hide
        tintColor = hide ? .clear : .white
    }
}
```